# Parse.com greater than returning duplicates

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm using this [PHP parse.com API library](https://github.com/apotropaic/parse.com-php-library) to retrieve rows from a table from *Parse*.

Due to the limit of maximum 1000 rows per request, I'm retrieving them in a *for* loop like this:

```
$lastUpdated = null;

$parse = new parseQuery($tableName);

$parseAllResults = array();
$skip = 0;

do {
    $index = count($parseAllResults) - 1;

    if($skip === 10000) {
        $lastUpdated = $parseAllResults[$index]['updatedAt'];

        $skip = 0;
    }

    $parseResults = queryParseCrawlObjects($lastUpdated, $skip);

    if (!empty($parseResults)) {
        $skip += 1000;
    } else {
        $skip = 0;
    }

    $parseAllResults = array_merge($parseAllResults, $parseResults);
} while ($skip > 0);

function queryParseCrawlObjects($parse, $lastUpdated, $skip) {
    global $parse;

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    $parse->orderBy('updatedAt');

    if ($lastUpdated != null) {
        $parse->whereGreaterThan('updatedAt', $parse->dataType('date', $lastUpdated));
    } else {
        $parse->whereNotEqualTo('objectId', '');
    }

    $parse->setLimit(1000);
    $parse->setSkip($skip);

    $results = $parse->find();

    return $results['results'];
}
```

I'm using the `whereNotEqualTo('objectId', '');` restriction as a workaround for a bug in the library, that practically retrieves all the rows, and the `skip` parameter ro retrieve them in a batch of 1000 rows.

Another limitation of *Parse* is that it doesn't allow a `skip` greater than 10.000. So I use the `updatedAt` field of the last row in the first 10.000 batch, as a restriction for the next rows.

And after the first 10.000 rows, it calls the `whereGreaterThan` method, that internally adds the `gt` *(greater than)* *Parse* parameter to the *curl* request.

The problem is that in the second loop step, it returns the same row as the last one from the previous step, and I get an error for duplicate `objectId` when I try to insert them into a database.

So the array looks something like this:

```
// first step
$parseAllResults[0] = array('objectId' => 'ihJikHNkjH', ...);
$parseAllResults[1] = array('objectId' => 'sHJKHfddkO', ...);
...
$parseAllResults[9999] = array('objectId' => 'rukBfcaDFR', ...);

// second step
$parseAllResults[10000] = array('objectId' => 'rukBfcaDFR', ...);
$parseAllResults[10001] = array('objectId' => 'gusFGvQWVs', ...);
...
$parseAllResults[19999] = array('objectId' => 'asHppNVAaD', ...);
```

with the 9999th and 10000th having the rest of the properties equal, so I'm sure it's the same row from *Parse* retrieved twice.

I don't understand why it does that, since it has a `whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo` method too, using the `gte` *(greater than or equal to)* *Parse* parameter.

#### TL;DR

**greater than** *(`gt`)* parameter behaves exactly like **greater than or equal to** *(`gte`)* parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This might fix your issue. Change this part of your code:

```
if($skip === 10000) {
    $lastUpdated = $parseAllResults[$index]['updatedAt'];

    $skip = 0;
}
```

to:

```
if($skip === 10000) {
    $lastUpdated = $parseAllResults[$index]['updatedAt'];

    $skip = 1;
}
```

Comment: Well, this is more like a workaround, which, although it works, doesn't answer my question